Is it feasible to create an online platform to effectively teach college-level math (abstract algebra, real analysis, etc.)?
I’m thinking about creating an online platform to teach college-level math subjects like abstract algebra, real analysis, topology, and other proof-heavy areas. A key challenge I’m facing is how to handle proof-writing, and I’d appreciate any insights on whether this is feasible.
Key Challenges:

Handwriting Proofs: I believe students should write proofs by hand, but this seems impractical for an online platform. Options like uploading photos of handwritten work or requiring tablets/styluses feel cumbersome. Are there better ways to manage this?

Feedback on Proofs: With many students, human feedback on every submission seems unrealistic. Are there any systems that could provide useful feedback on proofs without requiring extensive human grading?


In summary, is it even possible to build an online platform that effectively teaches college-level math courses that are proof-heavy?

I thought handwritten proofs might be easier for students starting out, but if they're comfortable with LaTeX, that's even better

@Servaes You have had a very different experience than my own.  As an undergraduate, I was somewhat unique, in that I used TeX and did not hand in handwritten work.  When I started graduate school, many of my compatriots had never used LaTeX.

I don't think it's possible to effectively teach college-level math that is proof heavy, online or not!

Your first challenge doesn't seem like such a problem, to me. I have done online submission of homework for large-ish in-person courses, and it works quite well. We require submissions by PDF. Most students take a photo or scan of their writeup using their phone, and it's readable. A minority of students do their work on a tablet, and this generates a PDF directly that they can upload. There are tools available that allow graders to give feedback directly onto the submitted PDF. To sum up, this aspect can be handled by existing platforms and is not really specific to proof-writing.
Your second challenge is a big deal. Even if we had a system that could determine how correct a proof written by a student is, in my experience most of the learning in a proof-based course happens when students are asking me why they lost points on a specific question, and I explain in extreme detail, physically pointing to their incorrect solution and maybe writing stuff on the board. The key thing is that the student can keep asking me questions until they actually understand. There are tools that allow this kind of interaction to happen remotely, but it can't be automated with any technology that exists today. It just requires a lot of manpower.
(Actually, I would argue that similar problems occur in non-proof-based courses like calculus, although perhaps not as severely. Online homework systems can be helpful, but relying on them too much does not lead to good learning outcomes, in my experience, and part of the reason is the lack of a knowledgeable human explaining to you why you got a question wrong. There is really no substitute for that.)

The thing you are most likely to have trouble with is that teaching a new student to write proofs is equally about checking correctness of the proof as it is a careful introduction and invitation to join a culture. To explain what I mean, consider this proof of the proposition "If an integer is even, then its square is even."

If $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is an even integer, then there is another integer $X$ where $x = 2X$. Now I will look at $x^2$. $x^2$ is the same thing as $(2X)^2$ which is $4X^2$, and multiples of 4 are even, so the proof is complete.

If you somehow get an automated proof-checker to exist, it will likely mark this proof as correct, because it is logically correct. However, it also is not an expert proof, because it has a very large number of cultural problems that a grader absolutely needs to help the student with. Here are the ones I purposely included; I'm sure you could find others:

Calling an integer $x$ is a little weird; call it $n$ or $a$ or something.
You shouldn't be saying "if... then" inside the proof; you should be starting with "suppose" and then making conclusions.
Calling the second integer $X$ is extremely strange; if you insist on the first integer being $x$ then the second one should definitely be $y$.
If you want to bring up a new topic, you say "Consider ...", not "Now I will look at ..."
If you insist on saying "Now I will look at," then you should really use the plural "Now we will look at."
It's inelegant to use the fact that multiples of 4 are even at the end of the proof. You could make things much better by taking one more step to show that your square is a multiple of 2, which is the definition of even you used at the beginning.
Speaking of which, you should really be using the phrase "by definition" when you use a definition.
Finally, you don't need to say "the proof is complete" if your proof is written well. Rewrite it so the last line shows that $x^2$ is even to avoid this.

An LLM like ChatGPT will actually be really good at correcting some of these stylistic cultural things, but your proof-checker that relies on things being correct cannot have anything to do with an LLM like ChatGPT, which never cares if things are correct. So you are going to have some trouble writing a good proof grader that handles both mathematical correctness and mathematical culture.
As a conclusion, I personally find the whole goal here abhorrent. Why would I want to outsource this cultural activity to a bot? I like inviting people into the mathematical community and showing them how to thrive in it. It's one of the best things about being in this community. It's not a chore that I hope to one day be free of. So I sincerely hope you do not succeed. Luckily, I believe it is currently impossible for you to succeed.

I can't sympathize with your strong feelings and intense language about stylistic choices such as variable names. Your example doesn't convince me. The style of mathematical writing is easy to pick up by reading others' proofs and mimicking them, whereas rigorous proofs are difficult and error prone. One could easily feed the proofs through an LLM transformer for style and a totally different bot for correctness.

The OP wants to serve as many learners as possible, to extend the gift of mathematics to as many students as possible. That's not abhorrent, it's a noble goal.

The example proof is too informal for a paper but gets the idea across to other mathematicians in conversation fine.

(FYI, I thought I had commented on this when you posted it, but apparently not. I did upvote it then.) Although my first impression was that your list is a bit harsh overall and included more than I'd try to "correct" when grading (unless one-on-one in office, talking; or only a handful of students in the class), it grew on me after a couple of minutes, especially the 2nd and 6th bullet items. And regarding being harsh, I guess I have no room to talk -- MSE example and Academia SE example.

@DaveLRenfro Thanks for the comment; I am always happy when you drop by with links. It makes the internet a better place. I do think the corrections you are making for real people in your links and the corrections I am making on this hypothetical student's paper are accomplishing the same thing: they are helping propagate a culture of precision and elegance that we love. Especially your linked point about $(X, +,\cdot)$ is exactly what I am talking about. Other commenters seem to believe that ChatGPT will save us from proofs including $(X, +,\cdot)$ where $+$ is never used, but I am skeptical.

Wow, when you mentioned "invitation to join a culture" I thought you were going to talk about how everyone is welcome in math, or about perseverance, etc. Instead you gave a proof (that I would be thrilled to see if it was the first proof a student ever wrote) and called it terrible.  I understand you meant something different by culture, but I think that language is important.  How many people are turned away by seeing "terrible" when there are many other options that still convey what you want.

@AdamBoocher I would also be thrilled if that was the first proof a student ever wrote! Your point is taken though; I'll edit "terrible" to something like "beginner."

I wouldn't focus on these style questions at all in an undergraduate course. The students who keep going with math will pick up the standard proof-writing style almost automatically.

Here's an additional example (from 7 years ago) of a MSE answer of mine about someone trying to overly-symbolize something, although I realize that sometimes you may want to do this for reasons other than trying to appear rigorous (e.g. for certain types of proof purposes, as in the earlier parts of this answer). I only became of that 7-years old MSE answer just now because it was upvoted in the last few hours (1st upvote I've gotten on that MSE answer, in fact).

Just got another upvote on that 7-years old MSE answer. I'm guessing you (Chris) just saw my comment here made 7 minutes ago, then saw that MSE answer, then upvoted it (maybe out of sympathy?).

@DaveLRenfro Nope, it must have been someone else reading all this!

Feedback on proofs can be provided by peers
A (partial) solution is to have the students provide proof feedback among themselves. This has the advantage that students also learn to give feedback and there is a lot to be learned from reading and trying provide constructive feedback on other people's work.
There are platforms like Peergrade to facilitate peer feedback in educational settings. I don't have first person experience with this, but I've heard good reports from my collaborators on using it in an online statistic class which has somewhat similar challenges to your situation.
The typical use case however is AFAIK that at some point, you can escalate to an actual expert instructors, if you feel the feedback you are getting is wrong/unfair. Still, this means the labor requirements can be substantially reduced.
A downside is that now you not only need to develop learning materials, but also build a learning community with strong friendly and collaborative culture. This is a very hard problem.
You may also note that Stack Exchange sites also rely on feedback from peers, so the model is definitely plausible even for an open forum.

Self-grading
This assumes that your prospective learners are not being forced to do this and not receiving a grade or credit. In this case, you don't need to find a way to assign grades automatically, you just need a way for students to assess the quality of their own proof.
For students already familiar with proofs, this seems reasonably simple. In most cases, when I turned in college math homework, I could estimate to within 5% what grade I would get, because I already recognized which parts of my work were flimsy and which parts were elegant. So for advanced courses, the self-grading answer key could be as simple as "Here's an example proof, and here's a couple common missteps to check for."
For introduction-to-proofs classes, the challenge is helping students identify the "unknown unknowns": any errors that they don't even realize are errors. For instance, proving something by using something that results from the conclusion itself. Your grading materials would need to be more in-depth and talk about why various parts of the proof are important. This answer to a different question suggests having students grade and correct example proofs. If they grade example proofs correctly, then they are likely grading their own proofs correctly. It also helps develop confidence that they are grading their proofs properly!
It seems useful to collect data about whether this method is working. Have students submit their proofs and a self-assessed rating based on the grading guide. You can randomly sample some of these submissions and grade them, and see when and how the scores diverge.
One remaining important issue is how to handle a proof that doesn't look at all like the example proofs but that the student still thinks might be valid. In this case, you probably need some "My proof doesn't look anything like the example!" button to flag it for peer-grading or instructor grading. That submission, right or wrong, could be added to the example proofs to help future students.
Related questions about teaching students to grade their proofs:

Teaching students how to check the validity of their proofs
Catalog of undergraduate's misconceptions / problems while proving
Taxonomy of bad proofs

